# How to validate radio button

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to validate gender from radio button.this is my code.but it's doesn't work.
javascript

```
function checkgender() {
  var gen = document.subscribe.gender[0].checked;
  var gen1 = document.subscribe.gender[1].checked;

  if((gen==false)&&(gen1==false)) {

    alert('Please Select your Gender Type!');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

html

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="gender">male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="gender">female
<input name="but" type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="checkgender()" />
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: didn't submit the button and didn't show alert.

Comment: You can refer this one http://jsfiddle.net/wyFQp/15/

Answer (score 0):

**Html:**

```
<input name="but" type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

**Script:**

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
   var gen = document.subscribe.gender[0].checked;
   var gen1 = document.subscribe.gender[1].checked;

   if((gen==false)&&(gen1==false))
   {
     <!--document.getElementById("fn6").style.borderColor = "#ED291F";-->
     alert('Please Select your Gender Type!');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`var gen = document.subscribe.gender[0].checked;
var gen1 = document.subscribe.gender[1].checked;`

Instead of this use

var x = document.getElementById("gender1").value;
var x = document.getElementById("gender2").value;

html

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="gender1">
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="gender2">
```

Or for complete example 
Visit

http://www.chennaisunday.com/jsradio.html

Answer (score 0):

finally i found a solution.thanks for your support

```
function checkgender()
     {
var gen = document.getElementsByName('gender');
var ischecked = false;
for ( var i = 0; i < gen.length; i++) {
    if(gen[i].checked) {
        ischecked = true;
        return true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!ischecked)   { 
    alert("Please Select your Gender Type");
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="rdbMale">male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="rdbFemale">female
<input name="but" id="btnGender" type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-rimary"/>
```

**Script**

```
$("#btnGender").click(function(){

  if(!$('#rdbMale').is(':checked') && !$('#rdbFemale').is(':checked'))
  {
    alert('Please Select your Gender Type!');
  }
```

});

Answer (score -1):

**check your onclick event**

```
<input name="but" type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="javascript:checkgender();" />
```

Comment: where is your script file located? Check you define script file path properly.

Comment: change your radio button **id** both having same id